# How to process GET Query String with Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask, vonage

How do I process a long GET request with Flask? Is is possible to get a dictionary all the params?

Here is the query string I'm trying to parse:

```
/?msisdn=19150000001&to=12108054321&messageId=000000FFFB0356D1&text=This+is+an+inbound+message &type=text&message-timestamp=2012-08-19+20%3A38%3A23
```

And Here is the code I have to far which only gets the 'msisdn' value:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def hello():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            json = request.args.getlist('msisdn')
            return str(json)
        else:
            return 'Hello World!'
```

Comment: Have you try `print request.args`

Comment: thanks you! such an obvious solution. I need to get a rubber duck

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.args) is a [`MultiDict`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    all_args = request.args.lists()
    return jsonify(all_args)
```

Comment: Same here! Did exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 25):

if you want to convert the query string (MultiDict to normal dict)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    all_args = request.args.to_dict()
    return jsonify(all_args)
```