# How to convert a query string to valid json?

Tags: python, flask

Is there an easy way to convert a query parameter string such as `'username=andrew&password=password1234'` to valid JSON  `{ "username": "andrew", "password": "password1234" }`

I have been trying to loop through the string and manually add parameters to JSON but I am curious to know if there is an easier way or a library available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to process GET Query String with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292766/how-to-process-get-query-string-with-flask)

Answer (score 4):

You can parse this to a dictionary that maps keys to a list of values:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

data = parse_qs('username=andrew&password=password1234')
```

this will give us:

```
>>> parse_qs('username=andrew&password=password1234')
{'username': ['andrew'], 'password': ['password1234']}
```

This is because a key can occur multiple times. If you are sure it only occurs once per key, you can use dictionary comprehension to convert it to a single item:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

data = { k: v
    for k, vs in parse_qs('username=andrew&password=password1234').items()
    for v in vs
}
```

and this produces:

```
>>> { k: v
...     for k, vs in parse_qs('username=andrew&password=password1234').items()
...     for v in vs
... }
{'username': 'andrew', 'password': 'password1234'}
```

You can make use of [**`json.dumps(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to convert it to a JSON blob:

```
>>> print(dumps(data))
{"username": "andrew", "password": "password1234"}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

using [urllib.parse.parse_qsl](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qsl)

```
import urllib.parse
import json
spam = 'username=andrew&password=password1234'
eggs = urllib.parse.parse_qsl(spam)
print(eggs)
foo = dict(eggs) # dict
print(foo)
bar =  json.dumps(foo) # JSON string
print(repr(bar))
```

output

```
[('username', 'andrew'), ('password', 'password1234')]
{'username': 'andrew', 'password': 'password1234'}
'{"username": "andrew", "password": "password1234"}'
```

Note: this is assuming only unique keys.

Comment: I just noticed you have both `flask` and `django` tags - maybe there is more to your question and there is probably tool in the framework, that you should/can be use to do what you actually want to achieve - e.g. the framework would have parse the query string for you into dict or similar. Obviously it's `flask` or `django`, so one of the tags is redundant.